# HTTP POST html data has 0 bytes

Tags: swift

I'm creating and HTML string that looks like this.

```
<form method='POST' action='https://secure.paygate.co.za/payweb3/process.trans'>
<input type='hidden' name='PAY_REQUEST_ID' value='653B3F12-3A86-EFE8-C96D-F1DD73B1E95F'></input><input type='hidden' name='CHECKSUM' value='F765B8AEA5F0D1067E1513832035BE76'></input></form>
```

I've tested the URL and paramaters using https://www.codepunker.com/tools/http-requests and I get the successful HTML response but for some reason I get an error HTML in respond when using the below code, http post.

```
let url = URL(string: self.dpoURL)!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod  = "POST"
request.httpBody    = postFormHtml.data(using: .utf8)
                
let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
  if error != nil {
    // Handle HTTP request error
  } else if let data = data {
    DispatchQueue.main.async{ [self] in
      // Handle HTTP request response
      self.resultFormHtml = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    }
  } else {
    // Handle unexpected error
  }
}
task.resume()
```

I have a feeling the issue is when I convert the HTML string to UTF8, postFormHtml.data(using: .utf8) because if I print that I get 0 Bytes. I also conducted the following test and get a blank text box.

```
let testHTML = postFormHtml.data(using: .utf8) 
viewHTML.text = String(decoding: testHTML, as: UTF8.self)
```

What am I doing wrong when converting my HTML string to data?

Answer (score 0):

It seems quite peculiar that using `.data(using: .utf8)` and then converting that back to String returns nothing. Having tried it in a playground with your input text I have no problems.

```
let string = """
<form method='POST' action='https://secure.paygate.co.za/payweb3/process.trans'>
<input type='hidden' name='PAY_REQUEST_ID' value='653B3F12-3A86-EFE8-C96D-F1DD73B1E95F'></input><input type='hidden' name='CHECKSUM' value='F765B8AEA5F0D1067E1513832035BE76'></input></form>
"""

let data = Data(string.utf8)
let decodedString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

Have you tried this in a clean playground yourself? It may be something else is affecting your `postFormHtml` variable.

Comment: Admittedly the API that I posted was different, but having tried it in the playground the API used in the question worked just like the API that I used here, it's just that mine didn't have the `data` as an optional, for the sake of clean usage.

Answer (score 0):

At the end Postman was the answer. I added the parameter in body, not param and then used the top right button CODE to have the code generated for me.

```
                        var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)

                        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: self.dpoURL)!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
                        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                        request.addValue("no-cache", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cache-Control")
                        request.addValue("paygate_payweb3=b09rqdgclqfi4gf7h261j79uke", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")

                        request.httpMethod = "POST"
                        request.httpBody   = postFormHtml

                        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                          guard let data = data else {
                            print(String(describing: error))
                            semaphore.signal()
                            return
                          }
                            self.resultFormHtml = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
                          semaphore.signal()
                        }

                        task.resume()
                        semaphore.wait()
```

Comment: I hope you didn't use that exact code. For one I'm really uncertain why one would need a semaphore in this instance, coupled with the fact that the timeout is set to be `infinity`, so the users could just get stuck without any errors propagating if there are network issues. Seems like some oddly generated code.